# Bootstrap 4 - aligning two layers of links to the top and bottom of a navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a collection of links I'd like to align to both the top and bottom of my `navbar`.  Specifically, this arrangement:

[image]

After playing with Irfandy Jip's code in the answer below, and my own continued research, I've come up withn this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange" style="border-bottom-width: 4px !important;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('_home') }}">
        <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo-sm.png') }}" class="d-lg-none">
        <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" class="d-none d-lg-block">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="navbar-nav color-dark-blue ml-auto flex-lg-column align-items-lg-start justify-content-lg-center order-lg-2">
            <div class="nav-item mb-lg-5">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-right border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-item mb-lg-5">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Login</a>
            <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Sign Up</a>
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 pt-5 my-lg-0 mx-auto d-inline w-50 order-lg-1" action="{{ path('_store_search_results') }}">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-burnt-orange my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav> <!-- end nav -->
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Which is *really* close to what I want, with the exception of how the entire `navbar` is growing at the bottom, no doubt the result of the margin's I've added (padding does the same thing).  Ideally, the social media icons would be on the same 'line' as the search bar, with the Login and Sign Up links at the top of the bar, as they currently are.

Here's a comparison with the rough draft of the layout:

[image]

Is there anything else I can do to make the links on the right look more like the last image?

Comment: The code doesn't match what's shown in the image. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @Zim I've posted the complete code in this edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve use css flextbox and `align-items: flex-end;`

Here is the updated snippet:

```css
form.form-inline {
  display: flex!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.form-inline .input-group,
.form-inline .nav-item {
  width: 33.33%!important;
}

.navbar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-item .btn-group {
  float: right;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0 1rem!important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    position: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange p-3" style="border-bottom-width: 4px !important;">


  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="navbar-nav color-dark-blue ml-auto flex-lg-column align-items-lg-start justify-content-lg-center order-lg-2">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-right border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Login</a>
      <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Sign Up</a>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 pt-5 my-lg-0 mx-auto d-inline w-50 order-lg-1" action="{{ path('_store_search_results') }}">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('_home') }}">
          <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo-sm.png') }}" class="d-lg-none">
          <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" class="d-none d-lg-block">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-burnt-orange my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED NOV 27, 2018,** Since question has been updated my old answer is no longer sufficient. Actually your answer is already answered a little by @Nandita, but since you liked my JSFiddle, I revised it again so it looks better.

You just have to set the "Search Bar" width yourself.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange d-flex justify-content-between" style="border-bottom-width: 4px !important;">
  <!-- Brand Logo -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('_home') }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo-sm.png') }}" class="d-lg-none">
    <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" class="d-none d-lg-block">
  </a>
  <!-- Toggler -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <!-- What's inside Toggler -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <!-- Search Bar -->
    <div class="ml-lg-auto d-none d-lg-inline" style="width:610px">
      <form class="w-100 m-auto" action="{{ path('_store_search_results') }}">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-burnt-orange" type="button"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- The Right Items -->
    <div class="navbar-nav color-dark-blue ml-lg-auto">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <!-- Login and Sign Up Button Group -->
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm d-none d-lg-inline-flex">
          <button class="btn btn-link border-right p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
              <a class="nav-link py-0" href="">Login</a>  
            </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link border-left p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
              <a class="nav-link py-0" href="">Sign Up</a>  
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Social Media Button Group -->
        <div class="btn-group-lg d-flex justify-content-around align-content-center my-lg-1 mt-lg-2">
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0">
              <i class="far fa-envelope d-none d-lg-inline"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook d-none d-lg-inline"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter d-none d-lg-inline"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Sign Up</a>

        <!-- Try pulling the panel to the left                                                           -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Link to JSFiddle to play around https://jsfiddle.net/irfandyjip89/y9fksubx/4/

Comment: That works really well for the top two buttons, so thanks for that :)  Please look at the edit I made to my original question... how would I put an additional series of links/buttons at the bottom of my navbar on the same side as login and sign up?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the  `mb-lg-5` class from nav-item

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>
</head>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange" style="border-bottom-width: 4px !important;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('_home') }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo-sm.png') }}" class="d-lg-none">
    <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" class="d-none d-lg-block">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="navbar-nav color-dark-blue ml-auto flex-lg-column align-items-lg-start justify-content-lg-center order-lg-2">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-right border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Login</a>
      <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Sign Up</a>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 pt-5 my-lg-0 mx-auto d-inline w-50 order-lg-1" action="{{ path('_store_search_results') }}">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-burnt-orange my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- end nav -->
```

**Additionally** , I  am also adding an alternative structure of HTML if you are flexible to changing the HTML structure. This structure is more responsive and as per the standards of bootstrap , the icons will be automatically be aligned to the search bar without the use of margins and padding.

```css
@media(min-width:992px) {
  .login-btn {
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  }
  form.search-form {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>
</head>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('_home') }}">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60" class="d-lg-none">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60" class="d-none d-lg-block">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 align-self-start">
        <li class="nav-item active login-btn ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
        <form class="search-form form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 mx-lg-auto d-inline w-100" action="{{ path('_store_search_results') }}">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-burnt-orange my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
      </button>
          <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve more like the example, i think you should just remove the padding in nav-item..and add padding in the nav class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange p-3" style="border-bottom-width: 4px !important;">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('_home') }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo-sm.png') }}" class="d-lg-none">
    <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" class="d-none d-lg-block">
</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="navbar-nav color-dark-blue ml-auto flex-lg-column align-items-lg-start justify-content-lg-center order-lg-2">
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-right border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-link border-dark-blue border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Sign Up</a>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 pt-5 my-lg-0 mx-auto d-inline w-50 order-lg-1" action="{{ path('_store_search_results') }}">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-burnt-orange my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"><i class="far fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and for your second question, just add another div with nav-item class

Answer (score 0):

here is what you want , check output in fullscreen :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light-blue border-bottom border-burnt-orange" style="border-bottom-width: 4px !important;">
    <a class="navbar-brand pt-lg-5 ml-lg-3" href="#">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="40" width="120" class="d-lg-none">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="40" width="120"  class="d-none d-lg-block">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mr-lg-3" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="navbar-nav color-dark-blue ml-auto flex-lg-column align-items-lg-start justify-content-lg-center order-lg-2">
            <div class="nav-item mb-lg-0">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-link  border-dark-blue border-right border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline" style="line-height:2px;">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link  border-dark-blue border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0 p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline" style="line-height:2px;">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-item mt-lg-0 pt-lg-4">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 d-none d-lg-inline">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Login</a>
            <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="">Sign Up</a>
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 pt-5 my-lg-0 mx-auto d-inline w-50 order-lg-1" action="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name="search" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```